# Random disconnection when not using WiFi enough

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10

I have a Desktop with Ubuntu 13.10 and I had to buy a WiFi USB dongle (Edimax EW-7811Un).

I installed some drivers and now it seems to be working, except for the fact that it disconnects about every 5 minutes.

I noticed that this doesn't happen when I'm talking on Skype or using BitTorrent.

So I tried to run a periodic ping :`ping -i 10 -s 1024 www.google.com` but doesn't seems to be working.

Any idea what this could be? Could it be that Skype keeps the connection alive because it is more "aggressive", or because it keeps continuously open a connection?

Comment: Is power management on or off? iwconfig

Comment: It is disabled. Running iwconfig I get `Power Management:off`. I initially thought it was something related to power management, but I presume that king of issue would not happen using periodic pings

Comment: Is the driver rtl8192cu or the compiled 8192cu? lsmod

Comment: Hi my friend. I am experiencing exactly the same problem. Did you find any solution that helped you with that?